# Sum all values of column A, find the first value of column B ordered by C, compare the sum with this first value to return a boolean

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=34d0f8dce0681aaad24623bbcb850159)

I need to sum all values `VALUEX` returned by a select with three where clauses, compare with another column value and return true or false, like this:

```
SELECT 
    // sum all VALUEX found (will be a list) and sum this result with a value passed by user (I am using JDBCTemplate to create the query and set parameters)
    // compare this sum with the first VALUEY found ordered by COLUMNCLAUSEORDER, 
    // in the case that the sum is greater return true, else false
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    VALUECLAUSEONE = '587c97e1-1fac'
    AND VALUECLAUSETWO > '2021-02-03'
    AND VALUECLAUSETHREE IN ('40', '20')
ORDER BY 
    COLUMNCLAUSEORDER
```

The query below returns the result as expected (although it doesn't return a bool), but I'm doing almost two times the same select. Is there a "prettier"/more efficient way to do that?

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN  t.m < (SELECT (SUM(COALESCE(CAST(VALUEX as DECIMAL(9,2)),0)) + 
                              COALESCE(CAST(10 as DECIMAL(9,2)),0))
                      FROM #mytable
                      WHERE VALUECLAUSEONE = '587c97e1-1fac' AND VALUECLAUSETWO > '2021-02-03' AND 
                      VALUECLAUSETHREE IN ('40','20')) 
         then '1' else '0' end 
FROM 
    (SELECT MAX(fv.f) as m from
     (SELECT 
         FIRST_VALUE(VALUEY) OVER (ORDER BY COLUMNCLAUSEORDER) as f 
     FROM #mytable
     WHERE VALUECLAUSEONE = '587c97e1-1fac' 
       AND VALUECLAUSETWO > '2021-02-03' 
       AND VALUECLAUSETHREE IN ('40','20'))fv)t
```

PS: It's for prod purposes, so I can't write it as a procedure

PS2: the number 10 in here `COALESCE(CAST(10 as DECIMAL(9,2)),0))` represents the value passed by user.

Columns data types:

```
VALUEX decimal(9, 2)
VALUEY decimal(9, 2)
VALUECLAUSEONE string
VALUECLAUSETWO datetime
VALUECLAUSETHREE string
COLUMNCLAUSEORDER integer
```

Sample of data, and an example of expected result:

MY_TABLE

```
|ID | VALUEX | VALUEY | VALUECLAUSEONE | VALUECLAUSETWO | VALUECLAUSETHREE | COLUMNCLAUSEORDER |
|1  | 10     | 33     |'587c97e1-1fac' |  '2021-02-03'  |     '20'         | 1                 |
|2  | 15     | 2      |'587c97e1-1fac' |  '2021-02-03'  |     '40'         | 2                 |
|3  | 5      | 40     |'587c97e1-1fac' |  '2021-02-04'  |     '40'         | 4                 |
|4  | 1      | 1      |'587c97e1-1fac' |  '2021-02-07'  |     '20'         | 5                 |
|5  | 30     | 1      |'587c97e1-1fac' |  '2021-02-09'  |     '40'         | 6                 |
|66 | 30     | 1      |'587c97e1-1fac' |  '2021-02-09'  |     '88'         | 6                 | <- will not count, doesn't match with where clauses
```

- User passed the number 10 by parameter to the query.
- Here, I'll sum all the VALUEX results = 61
- After, sum with the number 10 passed by the user = 71
- The first VALUEY found in ORDER BY COLUMNCLAUSEORDER is 33. So, I compare:

  - IF 71 (sum of all VALUEX + param) > 33 (FIRST VALUEY order by COLUMNCLAUSEORDER) returns true
  - ELSE returns false

In this example, the query returns true.

How the table structure looks like, and the inserts:

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable (
   ID                INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,VALUEX            INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,VALUEY            INTEGER 
  ,VALUECLAUSEONE    VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL
  ,VALUECLAUSETWO    DATETIME NOT NULL
  ,VALUECLAUSETHREE  VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
  ,COLUMNCLAUSEORDER INTEGER  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,VALUEX,VALUEY,VALUECLAUSEONE,VALUECLAUSETWO,VALUECLAUSETHREE,COLUMNCLAUSEORDER) VALUES (1,10,33,'587c97e1-1fac','2021-02-03','20',1);
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,VALUEX,VALUEY,VALUECLAUSEONE,VALUECLAUSETWO,VALUECLAUSETHREE,COLUMNCLAUSEORDER) VALUES (2,15,2,'587c97e1-1fac','2021-02-03','40',2);
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,VALUEX,VALUEY,VALUECLAUSEONE,VALUECLAUSETWO,VALUECLAUSETHREE,COLUMNCLAUSEORDER) VALUES (3,5,40,'587c97e1-1fac','2021-02-04','40',4);
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,VALUEX,VALUEY,VALUECLAUSEONE,VALUECLAUSETWO,VALUECLAUSETHREE,COLUMNCLAUSEORDER) VALUES (4,1,1,'587c97e1-1fac','2021-02-07','20',5);
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,VALUEX,VALUEY,VALUECLAUSEONE,VALUECLAUSETWO,VALUECLAUSETHREE,COLUMNCLAUSEORDER) VALUES (5,30,1,'587c97e1-1fac','2021-02-09','40',6);
INSERT INTO #mytable(ID,VALUEX,VALUEY,VALUECLAUSEONE,VALUECLAUSETWO,VALUECLAUSETHREE,COLUMNCLAUSEORDER) VALUES (6,30,1,'587c97e1-1fac','2021-02-09','88',6);
```

Comment: SQL Server or MySql?

Comment: This appears identical to your previous question? Please don't delete your question just to re-ask it. Improve the question and it will get re-opened.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, it is. I improved it, but since it  remained closed, I deleted it and posted a more detailed version.

Comment: To clarify, the query you posted works? You just want a more concise version?

Comment: Your script doesn't even run, it has data too large for column and duplicate primary key.

Comment: And enough with the `with (nolock)` - you should only use that in exceptional circumstances, and if you do you need to be very sure you understand how it works.

Comment: Your query returns 0, 0, 0 when I fix your errors and run it. Please ensure you have a [MRE] for us else this will get closed as well.

Comment: I also tried running your existing query against your test data (once I'd renamed the table to match) and it does not produce your expected result, it produces 3 rows value 0 - I can write you a more concise query to do that ;-))

Comment: @Stu  sorry, I don't have a personal computer, i'm using the company's notebook and i'm not allowed to create tables here. I created the table schema from a recommended site in another question.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you can create a [MRE] using [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)? e.g. [Test Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c76eee572aa1412b4d7641b2014909b)

Comment: @DaleK thankyou, I'll do it

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've half done it... modify the one I've linked, and get it working properly.

Comment: @DaleK Sorry for the delay, [here is the modified query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=34d0f8dce0681aaad24623bbcb850159)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all you are trying to do is avoid repeating the same query then just add your `SUM` as a window function to the main query e.g.

```
DECLARE @UserValue int = -20; -- use a variable then modify to test

SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN s.vd > s.vd1 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) TrueFalseValue
FROM (
    SELECT FIRST_VALUE(VALUEY) OVER (ORDER BY COLUMNCLAUSEORDER) AS vd
        --  Sum it all here
        , SUM(VALUEX) OVER () + COALESCE(@UserValue,0) vd1
    FROM #mytable
    WHERE VALUECLAUSEONE = '587c97e1-1fac'
    AND VALUECLAUSETWO > '2021-02-03'
    AND VALUECLAUSETHREE IN ('40','20')
) s;
```

Also you don't need all your `CAST`s - the original datatypes are fine. And using `MAX` at the very end seems cleaner.

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thank you!